# Метод модульного теста "не видит" тестируемый метод

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты

Доброго времени суток. Проблем с написанием тестов на консольных приложениях не было, но тут встал перед проблеммой, есть форма `MainForm` содержит в себе метод:

```
public double CountIt(double y, double r)
{
    return r * Math.Acos((r - y) / r) - Math.Sqrt(2 * r * y - Math.Pow(y, 2));
}
```

В проекте модульных тестов, тестовый метод не видит данную функцию, хотя ссылка на основной проект подключена.

```
public void TestCountIt()
{
    double checkIt = CountIt(5, 15);
    Assert.AreEqual(15, checkIt);
}
```

**Имя "CountIt" не существует в текущем контексте**

Comment: вы метод `CountIt` без самой формы пытаетесь запустить?

Comment: @tym32167, не понял вопроса, формы в тестовом проекте конечно же нет. Исходники необходимо добавлять и туда?

Comment: форма это тот-же объект, поэтом чтобы получить доступ к методу вам нужно либо создать его экземпляр либо сделать метод статическим. Я бы вообще вынес `CountIt` в отдельный класс.

Comment: Вы метод из формы тестируете? Если да, то чтобы вызвать этот метод, вам нужна форма.

Comment: `double checkIt = new Form1().CountIt(5, 15);`

Comment: @FoggyFinder, спасибо. Вопрос решен, давайте как ответ.

Comment: Это очень плохо, на каждый модульный тест создавать целую форму, а она там, может, при запуске еще и в БД идет и что-то загружает? Обязательно разделяйте классы по областям ответственности!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Форма это тот-же объект, поэтому, чтобы получить доступ к определенному методу нужно либо создать его экземпляр

```
double checkIt = new Form1().CountIt(5, 15);
```

либо сделать метод статическим.

Совет

Выносите все методы которые не связаны непосредственно с отображением в отдельные классы а еще лучше - в отдельную библиотеку. Это позволит вам при необходимости с легкостью перейти на другую платформу (например, WPF).